How to correctly display shaded area between two lines in ggplot2 using geom_ribbon?
I'm trying to create a plot in R using ggplot2 where I have two lines
representing percentages for two different groups (Male and Female) across different education levels. I want to shade the area between these two lines based on which group has the higher percentage.
However, I'm having trouble getting the shaded area to display correctly. Here's the code I'm using:
library(tidyverse)

desired_levels <- c("Ninguno", "Educación preescolar", 
                    "Educación básica primaria (1 a 5 grado)", 
                    "Educación básica primaria (6 a 9 grado)", 
                    "Educación Media (10 a 11 grado)", 
                    "Tecnológico sin graduar", 
                    "Técnico graduado", 
                    "Universitario sin graduar", 
                    "Universitario graduado", 
                    "Tecnológico graduado", 
                    "Técnico sin graduar", 
                    "Postgrado")

graph1 <- function(data, barrio) {
  # Filtering data
  data <- data %>% filter(`¿Cuál es el nivel educativo más alto que esta cursando o ha cursado?` != "No sabe, no informa")
  
  table <- data %>%
    group_by(`¿Cuál es el nivel educativo más alto que esta cursando o ha cursado?`, Género) %>%
    summarise(n = sum(EXPANSOR), .groups = 'drop') %>%
    group_by(`¿Cuál es el nivel educativo más alto que esta cursando o ha cursado?`) %>%
    mutate(percentage = n / sum(n) * 100) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    rename(NivelEducativo = `¿Cuál es el nivel educativo más alto que esta cursando o ha cursado?`)
  
  table$NivelEducativo <- factor(
    table$NivelEducativo,
    levels = desired_levels
  )
  
  table <- table %>%
    complete(NivelEducativo, Género, fill = list(n = 0, percentage = 0))
  
  # Creating bounds table for shaded area
  bounds <- table %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = Género, values_from = percentage) %>%
    mutate(
      ymax = pmax(Masculino, Femenino, na.rm = TRUE),
      ymin = pmin(Masculino, Femenino, na.rm = TRUE),
      fill = Femenino > Masculino
    ) %>%
    replace_na(list(Masculino = 0, Femenino = 0, ymax = 0, ymin = 0))
  
  plot <- ggplot() +
    geom_ribbon(data = bounds, aes(x = NivelEducativo, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, fill = fill), alpha = 0.4) +
    geom_line(data = table, aes(x = NivelEducativo, y = percentage, group = Género, color = Género), size = 1) +
    geom_point(data = table, aes(x = NivelEducativo, y = percentage, shape = Género, color = Género), size = 4) +
    geom_text(data = table, aes(x = NivelEducativo, y = percentage, label = paste0(round(n), " (", round(percentage), "%)")), 
              position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), size = 4, color = "black", vjust = -0.5) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("TRUE" = "#e31a1c", "FALSE" = "#1f78b4"), guide = "none") +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("Masculino" = "#1f78b4", "Femenino" = "#e31a1c")) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c("Masculino" = 21, "Femenino" = 23)) +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(title = "Nivel educativo más alto cursado por género en CB", 
         subtitle = "Distribución porcentual por género",
         x = "Nivel educativo", y = "Porcentaje (%)",
         color = "Género",
         shape = "Género") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, size = 12),
          axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
          legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
          legend.title = element_text(size = 12),
          plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 16),  
          plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 14),
          axis.title.x = element_text(size = 14),
          axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14),
          legend.position = "right",
          legend.background = element_rect(color = "gray", size = 0.1),
          legend.key = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "gray", size = 0.2),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          axis.line = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.5))
  
  return(plot)
}

graph1(data_cb, "CB")

However, the shaded area does not appear correctly between the two lines. Instead, it seems to be calculated incorrectly, with many NA values or improper bounds.
What am I doing wrong? How can I correctly display the shaded area between the two lines?
Actual output. 
desired output (concept):


As this answer shows you need to include the points where the lines intersect (where the fill color changes) for a clean result. If you need more help than that, please share some sample data--just the subset of data on either side of an intersection is plenty, we don't need all of it.

This is a nicer example showing the necessary interpolation.

@GregorThomas Thanks, Gregor! I fixed the error by adding a number to the x aesthetic of the geom_ribbon, which matches the order of the factors. This makes the shading appear, but there were problems at the intersections, as the post you mentioned describes. I resolved this with interpolation. Thanks again!
